# Pass image as string in deep link parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking

I know we can pass key/value pairs in deep link URL. but can we pass an image as string as a value for a particular key ? I know about inter app communication through shared container. In my case there is a framework created by us which other developer can integrate in their apps. Through framework the user can send an image to our application(if its installed). So shared container will not work here.
Any help will be appreciated.

**Is there any limit on the length of the url?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `base64StrImage` from source application

```
func gotToApp() {
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "img"))
    let base64Str = data!.base64EncodedString()
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "deep://")!) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "deep://?img=\(base64Str)")!, options: ["img": #imageLiteral(resourceName: "img")]) { (finish) in

        }
    }
}
```

Get Image In Destination Application.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        print(url.queryParameters!["img"])
        return true
 }

extension URL {
    public var queryParameters: [String: String]? {
        guard let components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true), let queryItems = components.queryItems else {
            return nil
        }

        var parameters = [String: String]()
        for item in queryItems {
            parameters[item.name] = item.value
        }

        return parameters
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a restriction on length of the url? I am more concerned whether it is this the right way also.

Comment: There is a no restriction for that. You can check Apple docs for further information

Comment: I tried to find about restriction on apple docs but could not. If you can point me to the link will be helpful

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan its may help you https://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan i passed  base64Str. it contains more then 5000 characters. its working charm.